# C# creates file with name <Debug><GivenName>

Tags: c#, visual-studio

This may be a stupid question, but I've been googling it for about 15 minuts now.
Actually the word "Debug" is not in the common context, that's why google results won't help me.

I'm using Visual Studio 2012.
I have a simple C# code that's suppose to print some output to .post file:

```
string sCurrPath = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()+"Posting_0";
TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(sCurrPath + ".post");
tw.WriteLine("something");
tw.Close();
```

This is a part of a for loop, but I don't think it matters.

I'm expecting to find a file called 
**"Posting_0.post"**
but what I get is a file called
**"DebugPosting_0.post"**

Maybe it's somewhere in the Visual Studio preferences.

When I try to look for answers in google, it misunderstands the context of "Debug".

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what do you expect `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()` to return?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()` would have `Documents/Visual Studio 2012/projects/yourProject/Debug` as the value, because you are currently running your project in the debug mode

so you might consider adding

`/Posting_0` instead of `Posting_0` to get the file with correct name inside the debug folder.

Answer (score 3):

use `Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "Posting_0")` instead of `+`.

Comment: System.IO.Path does not contain a definition for 'Join'.
Actually I'm new to c# and never worked with "Path", plus adding a slash helped, so I didn't really try to get it working. But thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

While debugging the current directory is Debug, so, you need to quit Debug from that path or put the file inside that folder for your program to work.

Answer (score 0):

What's happening, as others have alluded to but not stated explicitly, is the string returned by `GetCurrentDirectory()` doesn't have a trailing slash.  The executable is running from a subfolder of your project's folder called Debug (since you're in debug mode), E.G., `<project folder>\Debug`.  This is the build output folder.  You can change it to Release and you'll have a file with Release prepended in its name.  As Daniel White said, using `Path.Join()` will work as it will insert the directory separator (`\` on windows) and you'll wind up with your file named as expected in the debug folder.

As an aside, look at the `DirectoryInfo` class.  You can pass its constructor the output of `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()` then use that object's `Parent.FullName` property to get the directory to you exe's parent directory, E.g., your project directory.

EDIT: While it might seem ridiculous to have `Path.Join()` in the BCL since the path separator on windows is always `\`, it's there to remove the dependence/assumption that this is always the case.  It's a good idea to just force yourself to use `Path.Join()` instead of `\` because you never know what will happen to your code later on.